# Sublimetext3 + proxy from buildin python console

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, sublimetext3

I am behind of a **proxy** and trying to install the package manager for **sublime 3** on **windows 7**.

like https://packagecontrol.io/installation

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 475, in open
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_response
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 513, in error
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
  File "./urllib/request.py", line 595, in http_error_default
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

is there some other way to **set** the **proxy** ?

```
(I guess sublime 3 console is 
>>> import platform; platform.python_version();
'3.3.3'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to set 
windows environment variables list

```
http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:port
https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:port
```